# How do you correctly display entry tags within a tagger:entries_quick loop?

Tags: tagger

I have a News landing page with Tagger tags displayed by each entry. You can filter the view with tags, but once the entries are displayed within the `tagger:entries_quick` loop, the `tagger:tag_name` variable is overridden by the tag that defines the loop.

That is to say, all the tags for each entry render as the tag we're filtering by, but the `tagger:urlsafe_tagname` is correct.

Example:

Output of the standard entries loop output:

```
Related tags for this post:
<a href="/tag/tag-1">Tag 1</a>
<a href="/tag/tag-2">Tag 2</a>
```

Output of the `tagger:entries_quick` loop, filtered by Tag 1:

```
Related tags for this post:
<a href="/tag/tag-1">Tag 1</a>
<a href="/tag/tag-2">Tag 1</a>
```

Hopefully I'm missing something? Is there a different variable for use within this loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try utilizing the "prefix" parameter to avoid variable collisions:

```
{exp:tagger:entries_quick prefix="test"}
    <a href="{test:urlsafe_tagname}">{test:tag_name}</a>
{/exp:tagger:entries_quick}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I obviously didn't understand what that did.